# How to find and plot lower and upper limits of a line

Tags: matlab

In Matlab, how can one find and plot, e.g., the 10% lower and upper limits of a line. I would like easy to calculate and plot the 2 limit lines (blue; see example) given the red line.

```
stairs([repmat(1,[10 1]); repmat(3,[10 1]); repmat(2,[10 1])],'r'), hold on
stairs([repmat(1.1,[9 1]); repmat(3.1,[12 1]); repmat(2.1,[9 1])],'b--'), 
stairs([repmat(.9,[11 1]); repmat(2.9,[8 1]); repmat(1.9,[11 1])],'b--'), hold off
```

Hope above make sens. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In this very specific case, a solution that works is given below.

Input is **y** and the two desired outputs are obviously **up** and **dn**.

```
fraction = .1;

jUp = find(diff(y)>0);
jDn = find(diff(y)<0);

up = y + fraction;
up(jUp) = up(jUp+1);
up(jDn+1) = up(jDn);

dn = y - fraction;
dn(jUp+1) = dn(jUp);
dn(jDn) = dn(jDn+1);
```

but there exist many generalisations of this problem for which this simple approach does not work.

---

A more advanced approach (including a delta in x and y direction, and fixing problems with overlap or exceeding bounds) would be:

```
y = [1*ones([10 1]); 3*ones([10 1]); 2*ones([10 1])];

yFrac = .8;
xFrac = 5;

% generate x values
x = 1:numel(y);

% find indexes of change
idx = find(diff(y))+1;

% consider only changing points
yNew = y([1;idx;end]);
xNew = x([1;idx;end]);

% find indexes of positive and negative change
pIdx = find(diff(yNew)>0)+1;
nIdx = find(diff(yNew)<0)+1;

% determine down-shift
yDn = yNew - yFrac;
xDn = xNew;
xDn(pIdx) = xDn(pIdx) + xFrac;
xDn(nIdx) = xDn(nIdx) - xFrac;

% fix dn-values that overlap
oIdx = find(diff(xDn)<0);
yDn(oIdx) = [];
xDn(oIdx+1) = [];

% determine up-shift
yUp = yNew + yFrac;
xUp = xNew;
xUp(pIdx) = xUp(pIdx) - xFrac;
xUp(nIdx) = xUp(nIdx) + xFrac;

% fix up-values that exceed bounds
epIdx = find(xUp>xNew(end));
yUp(epIdx+1) = [];
xUp(epIdx) = [];
enIdx = find(xUp<xNew(1));
yUp(enIdx-1) = [];
xUp(enIdx) = [];

% plot results
figure(1)
clf
hold on
stairs(xNew,yNew,'b')
stairs(xDn,yDn,'r--')
stairs(xUp,yUp,'r--')
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this will work. However, I need also to have the intervals shifted, thus, there is "space" all around the input **b**. Like in my example, the amount of points change whether it is the lower or upper line. Do you know a way to get that? Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand your question. There is in fact a space of size 1 on the left and right side, due to the additional adjustments based on the jump indexes. The same space as in the example you gave in your question.

Comment: Sorry. With the code you provide I can control how much the limits is from the baseline. I a horizon manner. However, I would like to control in the vertical manner too. Can you help me with that? The lines will be plot by the function `stairs`, thus, we all this is considered discrete

Comment: I updated my original answer with an answer to your second question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I can see that the code change the number of elements compared to the input vector (y), which is not so good.